# How to make handler plugin to mysql in CentOS

Tags: mysql, plugins, makefile, installation

Environment: CentOS+mysql-5.6.14

This is what I tried:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
tar zvfx ahiguti-HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL-1.0.6-71-g159ea6d.tar.gz
cd ahiguti-HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL-159ea6d/

./autogen.sh
./configure --with-mysql-source=/usr/local/src/mysql-5.1.47 --with-mysql-bindir=/usr/local/app/mysql/bin/ --with-mysql-plugindir=/usr/local/app/mysql/lib/mysql/plugin/ --prefix=/usr/local/app/mysql
make
```

but when i do 'make', I encounter the following errors:

```
In file included from database.cpp:16:
mysql_incl.hpp:12:1: warning: "HAVE_CONFIG_H" redefined
<command line>:1:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
database.cpp: In member function 'virtual void dena::dbcontext::init_thread(const void*, volatile int&)':
database.cpp:294: error: 'LOCK_thread_count' was not declared in this scope
database.cpp:296: error: 'threads' was not declared in this scope
database.cpp:297: error: 'thread_count' was not declared in this scope
database.cpp:310: error: 'create' is not a member of 'MDL_request'
database.cpp: In member function 'virtual void dena::dbcontext::term_thread()':
database.cpp:337: error: 'LOCK_thread_count' was not declared in this scope
database.cpp:340: error: 'thread_count' was not declared in this scope
database.cpp: In member function 'void dena::dbcontext::cmd_find_internal(dena::dbcallback_i&, const dena::prep_stmt&, ha_rkey_function, const dena::cmd_exec_args&)':
database.cpp:649: error: 'struct st_key' has no member named 'key_parts'
/data/install/mysql-5.6.14/sql/handler.h:2228: error: 'virtual int handler::index_read_map(uchar*, const uchar*, key_part_map, ha_rkey_function)' is protected
database.cpp:689: error: within this context
/data/install/mysql-5.6.14/sql/handler.h:2247: error: 'virtual int handler::index_prev(uchar*)' is protected
database.cpp:694: error: within this context
/data/install/mysql-5.6.14/sql/handler.h:2244: error: 'virtual int handler::index_next(uchar*)' is protected
database.cpp:698: error: within this context
/data/install/mysql-5.6.14/sql/handler.h:2256: error: 'virtual int handler::index_next_same(uchar*, const uchar*, uint)' is protected
database.cpp:701: error: within this context
database.cpp: In member function 'virtual void dena::dbcontext::cmd_open_index(dena::dbcallback_i&, size_t, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*)':
database.cpp:770: error: cannot convert 'MEM_ROOT*' to 'Open_table_context*' for argument '3' to 'bool open_table(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, Open_table_context*)'
make[2]: *** [handlersocket_la-database.lo] error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL-1.0.6'
make: *** [all] error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried using the updated code (https://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL)?

Comment: yes,i had try the version with 1.0.6,1.1.0 and the master code.it did't work with the same error when i 'make'. but my company do it well with master code in the same computer.

Comment: https://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/issues/90

Comment: thanks,1.1.1 is Okhttps://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/issues/90

Comment: thanks,1.1.1 is ok [link](https://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/issues/90)

Comment: if 1.1.1 worked, you should make that an answer and accept it

Comment: yes,i also want to do that,but i don't konw how to make that an answer. where is the button or link to accept it?

Comment: click the checkbox next to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use version 1.1 of https://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL